# Apply spackling or skip ahead to primer?

Tags: painting, trim

Years ago, we decided to remove the wallpaper the previous owner had installed in the hallway of our house and were preparing to paint it when our plans got derailed and the project got put on the backburner until this weekend. I have a large surface area of moulding along the ceiling that is peeling which I’ve been scraping/sanding down, but I feel like it is too big of an area to apply the vinyl spackling that was recommended to me to even out the surface before the primer coat. Would I need to apply the spackling or am I just to keep sanding the peeled paint until the edges are flush? Do I put the first coat of primer on the scraped/unpainted areas only to "build up a layer"?  At the stage I'm at now, I feel that if I just apply the primer I will have an uneven surface where the paint was removed even though I've sanded the areas.

https://imgur.com/a/90iwiik

I am seeing conflicting directions on the path I need to follow. Most instructions regarding spackling is for nails and other small holes.

Comment: It's your house, it's your decision as to how particular you want to be. Bear in mind, that when it comes time to sell, potential buyers might be more picky than you.

Comment: I mostly want to make sure that I don't create a situation that results in additional peeling! :)  When we do sell this house, I'm going to let the professionals do their magic.
I am going to look into the skim coat process as I definitely have a room that needs that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no right answer. It all depends on a balance of how much time you have vs. what you consider to be an acceptable job.

All of that loose paint has to be scraped off. The moulding could take some filling with Bondo, and the walls could use a good skim coat. After all of that is done, I'd use latex caulk to fill the gaps between the molding and the wall. Clean the excess caulk with a wet sponge. Then prime, retouch, prime, paint.